# Probability that a student will pass both tests

Tags: probability

I'm trying to learn probability for a class and I can't wrap my head around this:

100 students appeared for two examinations. 60 passed the first, 50 passed the second and 30 passed both. Find the probability that a student selected at random has failed in both the exams.

If someone could solve this and explain how they went about it that would be great. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we know that 60 passed the first and 50 passed the second as well as an overlap of 30 passing both.  Let's take a look at the total space of 100 students:
[image]

Our goal is to find the number of people outside of the circles.

We know that overlapping space of the circles is 30 and for the first test that whole circle is 60 so the piece outside of the overlapping space is 60 - 30 = 30. For the second test circle the total space is 50 so the piece outside of the overlapping space is 50 - 30 = 20.

Now we have the overlapping space as well as the people who only passed the first test and the people who only passed the second.  So we just need to add these up and subtract from our total space of 100.

So 30 + 20 + 30 = 80 ==> 100(total space) - 80(space in circles) = 20(space outside of circles) ==> The probability is 20/100 or 1/5.